# Server.MapPath() get FileNotFoundException after published

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting FileNotFoundException on the server side, such as

> FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '\mml-cam02_REPORTS_MACHINE_20192.CSV'.

with my code:

```
string map_path = HttpContext.Current.Server
    .MapPath(@"~/MachineTimeReport/_MACHINE_20192.CSV");
using (var reader = new StreamReader(map_path))
  // ...
```

I already set the file security permission to "Everyone" and the file does exist in the path.  What are the reasons that could lead to this problem?  Thanks.

Comment: You could use ProcessMonitor to see where it is looking for the file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: '\mml-cam02_REPORTS_MACHINE_20192.CSV' *is not equal to* 'MachineTimeReport/_MACHINE_20192.CSV'

Comment: file names are difference?

Comment: I don't think so.  The "~/MachineTimeReport/_MACHINE_20192.CSV" is the virtual path that the file is shared on the server.  The other one is the physical path where the file is stored.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ProcessMonitor to see where it is looking for the file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon